# Remove common dictionary elements that are in 2 lists

Tags: python

I am trying to 'minus' out the common elements within 2 lists, however the elements within the 2 lists are dictionary.

Example:

```
list_dict_01 = [{'aaa':123}, {'bbb':234}, {'ccc':234}, {'ddd':456}]
list_dict_02 = [{'bbb':234}, {'ddd':456}]

res = list(set(list_dict_01)^set(list_dict_02))
# Expected output : `[{'aaa':123}, {'ccc':234}]`
```

However as I execute the code, I got the following errors:

```
# Error: unhashable type: 'dict'
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 4, in <module>
# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' #
```

What other ways can I do to achieve the result I wanted?

Comment: `[x for x in lst1 if x not in lst2]`

Comment: This works splendidly! I suppose the problem with mine is because I used `set`?

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
[item for item in list_dict_01 if not item in list_dict_02]+[item for item in list_dict_02 if not item in list_dict_01]
```

Comment: Hey, this works as well, but it does seems a bit long roundabout.. How is this different from the answer that Moses have provided?

Comment: I didn't see his answer when I posted mine, sorry for that. But in case there are items in your second list that are not in the first list, they will be added as well this way

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as the first answer suggested, with the use of `filter` function:

```
list_dict_01 = [{'aaa':123}, {'bbb':234}, {'ccc':234}, {'ddd':456}]
list_dict_02 = [{'bbb':234}, {'ddd':456}]

res = list(filter(lambda i: not i in list_dict_01, list_dict_02)) + list(filter(lambda i: not i in list_dict_02, list_dict_01))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[{'aaa': 123}, {'ccc': 234}]
```

Comment: it's better to use a list comprehension than filter. Not only because it's faster but it's a `functional programming` idiom and list comprehensions should be preferred.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Just presented it as an alternative to an already suggested answer.